# Why can't users can't access my Facebook canvas app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I have developed a canvas app. I can access the app through Facebook, but others can't see it and stuck in this page. The app is live.

ASP.NET MVC 4.

My permissions.vbhtml: (if you want other file please tell me)

```
    @Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook
    @ModelType FacebookRedirectContext
    @Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Required Permissions"
    End Code

    @If Model.RequiredPermissions.Length > 0
    @<h3>You need to grant the following permission(s) on Facebook to view this 
    page:</h3>
    @<ul>
    @For Each permission in Model.RequiredPermissions
    @<li>@permission</li>
    Next
    </ul>
    @<a class="buttonLink" href="@Html.Raw(Model.RedirectUrl)" target="_top">Authorize 
    this application</a>
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

please check that the sandbox mode is disabled or not in your app settings. If its enabled then only an admin can see that. Make it disabled so other users also view your app.